# Escaping closure for operators in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, operator-overloading, operators, currying

How can I store the function used to evaluate an operator in a variable in Swift?

Neither `Int.<` nor `` Int.`<` `` seem to compile for me.

For alphanumeric function names, this works just fine:

```
extension Comparable {
    static func lessThan(_ lhs: Self, _ rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs < rhs
    }
}

let comparator = Int.lessThan
```

I know I can create a new closure like this, but I feel like there must be a more elegant way:

```
let comparator: (Int, Int) -> Bool = {
    return $0 < $1
}
```

---

Please note that `<` actually is a static function on `Comparable` in Swift 3, and the top-level operator `<` only is a wrapper for that:

```
public protocol Comparable : Equatable {
    ...
    public static func <(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put brackets around it

```
let comparator: (Int, Int) -> Bool = (<)
```

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr Don't :) It's not at all obvious

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to access it as a property of the type, too? I'm guessing `(<)` refers to the top-level wrapper function, and *not* the actual static method on `Int`.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr Which static method on `Int`?

Comment: The less than symbol `<`, as defined as a requirement in `Comparable`.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr That conformance is satisfied by the "global" `<` operator. There's no `static func` on `Int` that does it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135229/discussion-between-alexander-and-christian-schnorr).

Comment: The Comparable protocol requires it, and Int conforms to Comparable. See [the relevant changes in Swift 3](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0091-improving-operators-in-protocols.md).